# Does 'estimateGas' behave the same on Ganache and on mainnet?

Tags: gas, ganache, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I noticed that [`estimateGas`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=estimateGas#methods-mymethod-estimategas) behavior in Ganache has changed:

In version 6.4.1, it throws an exception if exceeding the gas-limit.

In version 6.5.1, it returns the estimation even if exceeding the gas-limit.

I've been testing my script, and I had to update it according to this change.

What behavior should I expect on the mainnet? (I ask before I start spending my funds there).

Thank you!

Comment: Getting the same error